# Count frequencies and missing numbers in array

Tags: java, arrays, data-structures, time-complexity, space-complexity

You are given an array of n integers which can contain integers from 1 to n only . Some elements can be repeated multiple times and some other elements can be absent from the array . Write a running code on paper which takes O(1) space apart from the input array and O(n) time to print which elements are not present in the array and the count of every element which is there in the array along with the element number .

Here is the link to the problem and some solutions: 
http://www.careercup.com/question?id=21263687

Here is my solution:

```
import java.util.HashMap;

public class Question {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int arr[] = { 6, 4, 1, 4, 3, 2, 5, 2, 1,6,6,6 };
        freq(12, arr);
    }

    public static void freq(int n, int[] array) {

        int[] count = new int[n+1];
        for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
            count[array[i]]++;

        }

        for (int i = 1; i < count.length; i++) {

            System.out.println("number" + i + "frequency" + count[i]);

        }

    }

}
```

According to somebody else's solution, element present at any index can be overwritten and this can cause problem? We can sort the array in that case value present at index i is I+1 itself.

I dont understand why an element at an index can be overwritten?

Comment: why do you need `j` variable?

Comment: Are you aware your code uses O(n) space?

Comment: ya, cant think of a better solution. can some hints be provided?